# Why laptop GPU's are smaller than regular PC's GPU's

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, gpu

Maybe this is a stupid question to ask, but I was always wondering, why laptop graphics cards are significantly smaller than pc ones. Let's compare [Laptop with RTX 2080 Super](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0876L89TZ)

And some regular RTX 2080 Super - [RTX 2080 Super sample image](https://www.shwetacomputer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/zotac-gaming-geforce-rtx-2080-super-triple-fan_image_01_rgb-800x552.jpg)

And regular RTX 2080 Super is quite a bit bigger than the laptop itself. This laptop isn't even 3cm thick, where the only GPU seems to be exceeding that.

As I know, in Laptops only GPU main chip is soldered on (And VRAM ye ye ye...) But then the next question rises up. Why we can't just make some kind of GPU socket on the motherboard, and that would make PC's a lot smaller, excluding that bulky GPU PCB.

Comment: You're assuming that performance of the same card in a laptop and in a traditional form factor is identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the products carefully, you'll notice two really important things:

1. Desktop graphics cards (by volume and weight) are primarily made up of their cooling solution... The fans, metalwork and shoruds are all in an effort to get heat away from the various components - mainly the GPU die itself, RAM and power supplies. The shroud serves a secondary purpose as protection.
2. The "*really high*" performance laptops are *significantly* larger than the laptop you've linked to - they have a much more performant cooling solution, and often require use of two external power supplies to reach their full performance - they can't while running on battery power.

---

In a desktop environment, you have plenty of space, and essentially infinte power. There is no reason to design a smaller cooling solution that would be more costly and less performant... this enables you to run the components to their full potential, and to produce less noise while doing so.

A laptop on the other hand is in direct conflict with these points - size, weight and power consumption are all critically important to make a "*good*" product. The smaller cooling solution necesetates higher airflow, which leads to more fan noise while still performing worse than a larger solution.

To resolve these points, laptop graphics (and processors too) are often lesser products - the i9-10980HK is certainly no i9-10980K... the laptop part is 8 cores (upto 3.4GHz all-core turbo) with a 45W TDP, while the desktop part is 10 cores (upto 4.9 GHz all-core turbo) with a 125W TDP. There are other stats that suffer as well.

The "*Mobile*" suffix to "*NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Super*" is similar to Intel's "*H*". The parts are run with lower core and memory clock speeds, and therefore use less power and produce less heat, but are correspondingly less performant.

---

> Why we can't just make some kind of GPU socket on the motherboard, and that would make PC's a lot smaller, excluding that bulky GPU PCB.

If your real question was because you're looking for a small PC, then I believe I have seen "*small*" PCs that use mobile / laptop grapics and CPUs... but unfortunately I can't find one to link to right now... They'll typically be much more integrated, with the graphics and processor both soldered down, like a laptop. An obvious one to look at is the Intel NUC line up - some of which have integrated graphics, but some have full-sized PCIe slots.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about cooling and clock rates, as you can overclock CPUs, which generates heat, so the bigger PCs have extra fans and cooling ([info](https://www.chillblast.com/learn/whats-better-for-gaming-a-pc-or-a-laptop/#:%7E:text=Even%20today%2C%20with%20laptops%20getting,in%20PCs%20retain%20a%20lead)).

- Even with laptops getting better, a PC is still the best way to get the ultimate gaming performance. Graphics cards in PCs are still faster than equivalent chips in laptops, even though some graphics cores do feature in both PCs and laptops, and there are clear reasons why graphics cards in PCs retain a lead
- The cooler the better - PCs are larger and have better cooling systems so the same cores can run at far quicker speeds; the extra thermal headroom afforded by proper desktops means manufacturers can install overclocked graphics cards, which deliver an even bigger boost. Better thermal conditions also mean PCs use graphics cards that just aren’t available in laptops (like the high-end Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 Ti and Titan RTX)

Comment: Please use the correct markdown for weblinks

Answer (score 0):

Attie's answer is spot on, just one more point that isn't considered:

Desktop PC's are meant to be modular to some extent.  A built in GPU would almost be a hindrance in the world of desktop PC's.  The fact that you can very easily add or remove hardware in a desktop PC is a massive selling point.

- Want to customize it?  Simple.
- Something broken?  Replace it.
- Want a new PC case with integrated water cooling?  Save money, buy the case and transfer your hardware to it.
- Want to upgrade?  Just do it.

My view of desktop PC's is that they are inherently perfect for customization.  The hardware is built to be modular to make them easy to work with.  Built in hardware therefore is a bit pointless.  I'm sure there are pro's to it, but in general there's little point.

Comment: You're correct, but I don't think you're answering the question asked. It was "why aren't desktop GPUs smaller", not "why aren't desktop GPUs integrated" (they are, by the way).